# Double string to int

Tags: python

```
>>> s = "'8255'"
>>> int(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'8255'"
```

Is there a handy function that will take regular string, or this kind of double string as in example, and produce integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "'8255'"
# note - this still works if it was '"8255"'
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
'8255'
>>> int(ast.literal_eval(s))
8255
```

It also has the advantage that given something that's already an int...

```
>>> s = '8255'
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(s))
<type 'int'>
```

You automatically get back an int...

see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 2):

Some other options include:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "'8255'"
>>> s = int(re.sub("\D", "", s))
```

and

```
>>> s = "'8255'"
>>> s = int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s))'
```

---

***Edit:*** out of curiosity I decided to test the times of some of the suggested options.

```
def reMethod(s):
    import re
    return int(re.sub("\D", "", s))

def filterMethod(s):
    return int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s))

def evalMethod(s):
    return int(eval(s))

def literalMethod(s):
    import ast
    return int(ast.literal_eval(s))

def stripMethod(s):
    return int(s.strip("\'").strip("\""))

if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    s = ...
    t1 = Timer(lambda: reMethod(s))
    t2 = Timer(lambda: filterMethod(s))
    t3 = Timer(lambda: evalMethod(s))
    t4 = Timer(lambda: literalMethod(s))
    t5 = Timer(lambda: stripMethod(s))
    print t1.timeit(number=10000)
    print t2.timeit(number=10000)
    print t3.timeit(number=10000)
    print t4.timeit(number=10000)
    print t5.timeit(number=10000)
```

Output when s is small (4 digits):

```
reMethod = 0.0482196671653
filterMethod = 0.0266420145487
evalMethod = 0.0923773329062
literalMethod = 0.108779595759
stripMethod = 0.0165356828523
```

Output when s is large (150 digits):

```
reMethod = 0.068626707014
filterMethod = 0.28342855188
evalMethod = 0.116445492177
literalMethod = 0.134001262669
stripMethod = 0.0227778106058
```

Output when s is really large (7500 digits):

```
reMethod = 4.40808699357
filterMethod = 16.7396360029
evalMethod = 4.72486805726
literalMethod = 4.52914962633
stripMethod = 3.65296183068
```

Overall it seems they don't differ that much in performance. `filter` is about the only one that gets slower as the digits get longer. Take from this what you will, I was just curious to see the results and thought others might be as well.

Comment: +1 I really like that you took the time to time each solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try use builtin function `eval`:

```
new_s = int(eval(s))
```

Comment: I accepted `literal_eval`, as this code isn't just for me. It's additional import just to do conversion, but it's more strait-forward then `re`, which I initially thought to use before asking

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is dangerous. This might not be the most optimized solution. But a safe and flexible.

```
import re

s = "'8255'"

def find_ints(s):
    m = re.search('\d+', s)
    if m:
        return int(m.group(0))
    return None

find_ints(s)
Out[4]: 8255
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` like this:

```
>>> s = "'8255'"
>>> int(eval(s))
8255
```

This works also with regular string:

```
>>> s = '8225'
>>> int(eval(s))
8255
```

If you vant to remove more " and ' use nested `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

try stripping undesired characters:

```
int(s.strip("\'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing appears to be parsing a *literal* contained in another literal.

While `eval(eval("'123'"))` would do the trick, `eval` should generally be avoided because it will also execute any arbitrary code in the expression.

Fortunately, there is a standard module available that does precise evaluation: [ast - Abstract Syntax Trees](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval
number = literal_eval(literal_eval(s))
```